# Grouping by Multiple Columns if value yes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

If I have multiple columns that I want to group by such as,

```
User | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday | Enrolled. 
3     Yes      No          Yes         No        Yes      No          No
2      No      No          Yes         No         No      No         Yes
4      No      No           No         No         No      No         No
```

What would be best method to group by day to see how many yes occur for each user?

Expected Output:

```
Day     |  Amount
Monday     1
Tuesday     0
Wednesday   2
...
```

Comment: You have more that one Monday, Tuesday, etc.. in  your real dataframe?

Answer (score 2):

We do not need to groupby

```
s = df.set_index('User').eq('Yes').sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: There are other columns in the df that are not day I just did not show, but I updated the df to show - thanks!

Comment: This doesnt take into account column name? Since I have other columns

Comment: @Chris90 you can filter it then do above df[['columns......]].eq('Yes').sum(axis=1)

Comment: sorry I dont follow, i wanted my output to be grouped by day , thanks

Comment: there are columns in my df that have yes as a value that are not day that i dont want to compute

Comment: @Chris90 what you mean grouped by day, I only see unique day in columns ....